# Subsequent Launch after uncalled onDestroy shows a blank screen

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

I am using a `WebView` in my app's sole `Activity`. Whenever the user clicks on the BACK button, I override the `onKey` and process some clean up before calling `finish` of the activity.

I see that once in a while (maybe 1 out of 20 times), `onDestroy` is not called. And in this case, if I launch my app again, a blank screen comes up. The Activity's `onCreate` is not called, and neither is my overridden Application's `onCreate`.

Does anyone know why this happens, and are there any possible solutions?

Thanks,
Rajath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was capturing uncaught exceptions using the `UncaughtExceptionHandler()`. So, sometimes when the app was actually crashing in `onDestroy()`, the subsequent session was not properly launched.

Of course, in the case where the app's `onDestroy()` was not called at all, the problem is still fixed when I don't use `UncaughtExceptionHandler()`. Not sure why though.

-Rajath

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little less than a line of code you have provided, please do the following:

1. Stop overriding back key.
2. Do the cleanup elsewhere, e.g., in `onPause()`.